# SQL server compare multiple columns and display text when two values match

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple columns identifying body area injured:

```
ID      head    face    thor   abdo    spine   area injured
4721    5       0       5      3       0       multiple 
4723    0       0       0      3       3       multiple
4737    0       0       1      3       0       abdo
4752    0       2       0      0       0       face
```

At present, the [area injured] column is based on the column that contains the highest value, if two columns have the joint highest value, it lists 'multiple'.

I want to change the [area injured] column and list the actual body areas instead of 'multiple', for example:

```
ID      head    face    thor   abdo    spine   area injured
4721    5       0       5      3       0       head, thor   
4723    0       0       0      3       3       abdo, spine
4737    0       0       1      3       0       abdo
4752    0       2       0      0       0       face
```

How do I compare the five columns to establish which columns have the highest values?

Comment: is this how its stored or is it flattened into a table where head,face, thor, abdo and spine are rows? what populates the areainjured column currently?

Comment: The table I have access to has the data stored as above, it is created as scheduled job and the area injured column is derived as part of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `CASE` expressions find the columns with the largest value:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09100/2/0)

```
SELECT *,
    [area injured] =
        STUFF((
            CASE WHEN head >= face AND head >= thor AND head >= abdo AND head >= spine THEN ', head' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN face >= head AND face >= thor AND face >= abdo AND face >= spine THEN ', face' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN thor >= head AND thor >= face AND thor >= abdo AND thor >= spine THEN ', thor' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN abdo >= head AND abdo >= face AND abdo >= thor AND abdo >= spine THEN ', abdo' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN spine >= head AND spine >= face AND spine >= abdo AND spine >= thor THEN ', spine' ELSE '' END
        ), 1, 2, '')
FROM tbl
```

---

Another way, which is more dynamic, is to `UNPIVOT` your data and use `RANK` to get the column with the highest value. Then, use `FOR XML PATH('')` for concatenation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09100/1/0)

```
WITH CteUnpivot AS(
    SELECT
        t.ID, x.col, x.value
    FROM tbl t
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES
        ('head', t.head),
        ('face', t.face),
        ('thor', t.thor),
        ('abdo', t.abdo),
        ('spine', t.spine)
    )x(col, value)
),
CteRn AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY value DESC)
    FROM CteUnpivot
)
SELECT 
    c.ID,
    [area injured] =
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + col
            FROM CteRn
            WHERE
                ID = c.ID
                AND rn = 1
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1 ,2, '')
FROM CteRn c
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

To `UPDATE` values in `area_injured` column you can use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/679c2/24/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID
    ,area_injured = REPLACE((SELECT 
                              IIF(t1.head = cr.val, 'head, ', '') +
                              IIF(t1.face = cr.val, 'face, ', '') +
                              IIF(t1.thor = cr.val, 'thor, ', '') +
                              IIF(t1.abdo = cr.val, 'abdo, ', '') + 
                              IIF(t1.spine = cr.val, 'spine, ', '') + ';'
                            FROM tab t1
                            WHERE t.ID = t1.ID), ', ;', '')
  FROM tab t
  CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(v)
              FROM (VALUES (t.head),
                           (t.face),
                           (t.thor),
                           (t.abdo),
                           (t.spine)) AS c(v)) AS cr(val)
)
UPDATE t
SET area_injured = c.area_injured
FROM tab t
JOIN cte c
  ON t.id = c.id;

SELECT *
FROM tab;
```

1. `CROSS APPLY` will get `MAX` value from columns with body part
2. Correlated subquery build `area_injured` string
3. Update original table based on Id

Answer (score 1):

You case use UNPIVOT to achieve this

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07a18/1)

```
WITH CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ID,HEAD,FACE,THOR,ABDO,SPINE
     FROM PARTSDATA) T
        UNPIVOT
        ( QUANTITY FOR PART IN
        (HEAD,FACE,THOR ,ABDO , SPINE)
        ) AS U
),
CTE3 AS
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC) AS RN,QUANTITY,PART,ID
    FROM CTE2
)

SELECT DISTINCT C1.ID,STUFF(DT.CONTENT,1,1,'') AS [AREA INJURED] 
FROM CTE3 C1
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT ','+PART 
                    FROM CTE3
                    WHERE ID = C1.ID AND RN=1 FOR XML PATH(''))DT(CONTENT)
WHERE RN=1
```